# which() function in R - after sorting in descending order, issues matching with duplicate values

Tags: r, zipcode

I'm trying to find the next closest store from a matrix of store IDs, zip codes, and long/latitude coordinates for each of the zip codes. Trouble happens when there are more than 1 store per zipcode, and the script doesn't know how to order 2 values that are identical (store x is 10 miles away, store y is 10 miles, and has trouble with the order of x and y, and is returning (c(x,y)), instead of x,y or y,x). I need to find a way to have my code figure out how to list both of them (arbituary order since they are the same distance away from the store, based on zip code).

I'm thinking there can likely be modifications to the which() function, but I'm not having any luck.

Note that all the stores run, just the 100 or so stores that have the same zipcode as another store get tripped up - I'd love to not manually go through and edit the csv.

```
library(data.table)
library(zipcode)
library(geosphere)
source<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\mcan\Desktop\\Projects\\Closest Store\\Site and Zip.csv",header=TRUE, sep=",") #open
zip<-source[,2] #break apart the source zip codes 
ID<-source[,1] #break apart the IDs
zip<-clean.zipcodes(zip) #clean up the zipcodes 
CleanedData<-data.frame(ID,zip) #combine the IDs and cleaned Zip codes
CleanedData<-merge(x=CleanedData,y=zipcode,by="zip",all.x=TRUE) #dataset of store IDs, zipcodes, and their long/lat positions
setDT(CleanedData) #set data frame to data table 
storeDistances <- distm(CleanedData[,.(longitude,latitude)],CleanedData[,.(longitude,latitude)]) #matrix between long/lat points of all stores in list 
colnames(storeDistances) <- rownames(storeDistances) <- CleanedData[,ID] 
whatsClosest <- function(number=1){
    apply(storeDistances,1,function(x) (colnames(storeDistances)[which(x==sort(x)[number+1])])) #sorts in descending order and picks the 2nd closest distance, matches with storeID
}
CleanedData[,firstClosestSite:=whatsClosest(1)] #looks for 1st closest store
CleanedData[,secondClosestSite:=whatsClosest(2)] #looks for 2nd closest store
CleanedData[,thirdClosestSite:=whatsClosest(3)] #looks for 3rd closest store
```

Data set format:

```
 Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 1206 obs. of  9 variables:
     $ zip              : Factor w/ 1182 levels "01234","02345",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
     $ ID               : int  11111 12222 13333 10528 ...
     $ city             : chr  "Boston" "Somerville" "Cambridge" "Weston" ...
     $ state            : chr  "MA" "MA" "MA" "MA" ...
     $ latitude         : num  40.0 41.0 42.0 43.0 ...
     $ longitude        : num  -70.0 -70.1 -70.2 -70.3 -70.4 ...
    $ firstClosestSite :List of 1206
      ..$ : chr "12345"
    $ secondClosestSite :List of 1206
      ..$ : chr "12344"
    $ thirdClosestSite :List of 1206
      ..$ : chr "12343"
```

Issue comes with the firstClosestSite and secondClosest site, they are sorted by distance, but if the distance is the same because two stores exist in the same zipcode, the which() function (I think) doesn't know how to account for this, so you get this awkward concatenation in the CSV:

```
StoreID      Zip       City       State    Longitude  Latitude FirstClosestSite
11222       11000     Boston      MA       40.0       -70.0    c("11111""12222")
    
SecondClosestSite     ThirdClosestSite
c("11111"    "12222")   13333
```

Example of how the distance matrix is formed (store IDs in first row and column, with the matrix values being the distance between store IDs):

```
    11111   22222     33333   44444   55555   66666
11111   0      6000    32000   36000  28000   28000
22222   6000    0      37500   40500  32000   32000
33333   32000   37500   0      11000   6900   6900
44444   36000   40500   11000   0     8900    8900
55555   28000   32000   6900    8900    0     0
66666   28000   32000   6900    8900    0     0
```

Issue is the duplicates in each row... the which() doesn't know which store is closest to 11111 (either 55555 or 66666).

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your dataset and of the final result that you're looking for?

Comment: @OriolMirosa Just editted! There needs to be a decision made between sites 11111 or 12222, for example - too tedious to go through the CSV and fix these rows ~ any ideas? :P

Comment: @OriolMirosa I'm looking for an alternate to the which() function

Comment: What I would do is expand the lambda function in the `apply` so that, before  checking for the store ID, you check the `length` of the `which()` statement. If the `length` is 1, you proceed, normally. If it is larger than 1, then you can deal with the case. It's hard for me to play around with this without at least a sample of the dataset, so if you can't figure it out post or send me a version of your data and I can help you further.

Comment: got it! thanks @OriolMirosa

Comment: @OriolMirosa - ran into a problem... looks like for some of the stores, if they have the same zip code as another store , x[1] actually ends up being the store itself... for example - store 11111 and 2222 are the same zipcode, and 33333 and 44444 are the next closest stores - first closest site for 11111 would be 11111, 33333, 44444... I changed df$store to [1:4], for a few of them I get store: 11111, x[0] 22222, x[1] 11111, x[2] 33333, etc. - any thoughts? I'm thinking an if statement that would check to make sure x[1] did not equal the storeID - hmm

Comment: You are right. I modified the script below, and I explained the changes in comments. Let me know if anything is unclear, but I think it should work now.

Comment: @OriolMirosa - getting there! One thing I am noticed is that for stores that have the same zip code (a zip code that is closest to the store), only one of the stores comes up in the ordered list, and it essentially skips over the other store in that zip code that is essentially tied for the closest. Does that make sense? Say we're looking at Store 1 - Store 1 is closest to Store 2,3 (because they are in the same zip), and 4, 5 (are the next closest) - the matrix essentially lists 2,4,5 as the next closest stores... any thoughts?

Comment: @OriolMirosa I am specifically looking at the whatsClosestListRemoveSelf matrix by : write.csv(whatsClosestListRemoveSelf,"C:\\Users\\mcan\\Desktop\\Closest Store\\Remove.csv",row.names=F)  - noticing the oddity above, but otherwise, the 2 stores have the same distance from other stores - but only when they're the closest stores does this issue come up.

Comment: @OriolMirosa   my thoughts are that the issue is inthe whatsClosestRemoveSelf function - maybe the exclude (!) only applies to the store IDS and not actually the distances themselves?

Comment: Are you sure that is the problem? Everything seemed to work well here in my end, but I realized that when I made the last batch of changes eliminating the distances of a store to itself, I forgot to change the range of stores chosen for the first three: it used to be `2:4`, because we tried to ignore itself, but now that the store itself is not there, that should be changed to `1:3`. So this is the line modified: `whatsClosestTopThree <- lapply(whatsClosestOrderedList, function(df) { df$store[1:3] })` I already made the changes below. Let me know if this fixes it.

Comment: I JUST FIGURED THAT OUT ha it should be 1:3 - thank you !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a solution. Everything up until the line with `colnames(storeDistances) <- ...` stays the same. After that, you should replace the code with the following:

```
whatsClosestList <- sapply(as.data.frame(storeDistances), function(x) list(data.frame(distance = x, store = rownames(storeDistances), stringsAsFactors = F)))

# Get the names of the stores
# this step is necessary because lapply doesn't allow us
# to access the list names
storeNames = names(whatsClosestList)

# Iterate through each store's data frame using storeNames
# and delete the distance to itself
whatsClosestListRemoveSelf <- lapply(storeNames, function(name) {
  df <- whatsClosestList[[name]]
  df <- df[!df$store == name,]
})

# The previous step got rid of the store names in the list,
# so we add them again here
names(whatsClosestListRemoveSelf) <- storeNames

whatsClosestOrderedList <- lapply(whatsClosestListRemoveSelf, function(df) { df[order(df$distance),] })

whatsClosestTopThree <- lapply(whatsClosestOrderedList, function(df) { df$store[1:3] })

firstClosestSite <- lapply(whatsClosestTopThree, function(x) { x[1]} )
secondClosestSite <- lapply(whatsClosestTopThree, function(x) { x[2]} )
thirdClosestSite <- lapply(whatsClosestTopThree, function(x) { x[3]} )

CleanedData[,firstClosestSite:=firstClosestSite] #looks for 1st closest store in list
CleanedData[,secondClosestSite:=secondClosestSite] #looks for 2nd closest store in list 
CleanedData[,thirdClosestSite:=thirdClosestSite] #looks for 3rd closest store in list
```

Basically, instead of searching only for the (first, second, third) closest site, I create a list of dataframes for each store with the distance to all other stores. I then order these dataframes, and extract the three closest stores, which sometimes include ties (if tied, they're ordered by the name of the store). Then you only need to extract a list with the firstClosestSite, secondClosestSite, etc., for each store, and that's why you use in the search in `CleanedData`. Hope it works!

Comment: Yep, I forgot the equal sign when I copied this. I'm glad it works now!